# How to add route with busybox (for specified destination and gateway)

Tags: busybox

I tried the code:

```
alias netstat='/system/xbin/busybox netstat'
alias grep='/system/xbin/busybox grep'
alias awk='/system/xbin/busybox awk'
alias route='/system/xbin/busybox route'

gateway=`netstat -rn | grep ^0\.0\.0\.0 | awk '{print $2}'`

route add -net 1.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw $gateway
```

It doesn't run and print out the manual for route command...

Does busybox support `route add -net $des netmask $mask gw $gateway`? If so what did I do wrong?

Update: I tried to update to magisk 12.0, and now it just shows applet not found instead...

So I did try `/data/magisk/busybox route` This gives me applet not found again. Then I tried `/dev/busybox/route` It prints '/dev/busybox/route not found'. I checked and the file '/dev/busybox/route' exists (as a shortcut), so I am not sure what is going on anymore. BTW, I did run su before I tried to run these commands.

Also if I run these commands line by line, I will get different error message than "not found" when I put them in a .sh file and run `sh script.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magisk:

`/dev/busybox/route add -net 1.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw $(getprop net.dns1)`

Busybox:

`/system/xbin/busybox route add -net 1.0.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw $(getprop net.dns1)`